# req.params.id returning undefined when id is defined in separate file

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

When I use `req.params.id` with mongoose it returns undefined. I am fairly certain this is because I define the id parameter in my `app.js` and not my route file.

**Route file:**

```
//NEW - Form for adding new course
router.get("/new", function(req, res) {
    // find course by id
    Course.findById(req.params.id).exec(function(err, foundCourse) {
        if(err) {
            res.redirect("back");
        } else {
            //show template with correct id
            res.render("lectures/new", {course: foundCourse});
        }
    });
});
```

**App.js file:**

```
app.use("/courses/:id/lectures", lectureRoutes);
```

Is there any way to fix this so that I can access the id parameter from the route file?

EDIT:
the path I use in my browser:

```
http://localhost:7000/courses/5a4111286ae1111f541c3d88/lectures/new
```

Comment: Can you post the `path` you are using in your browser or test to call this?

Comment: Added the path now

Comment: I am not sure, but I think `findById` does not cast the id into `ObjectId`, which is required in query. Also did you log the value of req.params.id?

Comment: This works completely fine if I remove the app.use path and instead insert it directly into to route file.

When I logged the req.params.id I got undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this to work you have to enable the option called `mergeParams`.

```
const router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });
```

See the documentation [here](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.router).